# A* Pathfinding implementation error leads to infinite loop

Tags: javascript, path-finding, a-star

I seem to have a error in the following A* pathfinding implementation, which I implemented based on the pseudocode found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171022224528/http://www.policyalmanac.org:80/games/aStarTutorial.htm).

```
function NodeList() {
    this.nodes = [];

    this.add = function(givenNode) {
        for(var i = 0; i<this.nodes.length; i++) {
            if(this.nodes[i].f <= givenNode.f) {
                this.nodes.splice(i, 0, givenNode);
                return;
            }
        }
        
        this.nodes.push(givenNode);
    }
    
    this.pop = function() {
        return this.nodes.splice(this.nodes.length-1, 1)[0];
    }
    
    this.getNode = function(givenNode) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.nodes.length; i++) {
            if (this.nodes[i].pos.x == givenNode.pos.x && this.nodes[i].pos.y == givenNode.pos.y) {
                return this.nodes.splice(i, 1)[0];
            }
        }
                
        return -1;
    }
    
    this.hasNode = function(givenNode) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.nodes.length; i++) {
            if (this.nodes[i].pos.x == givenNode.pos.x && this.nodes[i].pos.y == givenNode.pos.y) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
    
    this.length = function() {
        return this.nodes.length;
    }
}

function PathNode(pos, f, g, h) {
    this.pos = pos;
    this.f = f;
    this.g = g;
    this.h = h;
}

function FindPath(start, goal) {
    var x_array = [0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1];
    var y_array = [1, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1];
    
    var open_list = new NodeList();
    open_list.add(new PathNode(start, start.Manhattan(goal) * 10, 0, start.Manhattan(goal) * 10));
    var closed_list = new NodeList();
        
    while(open_list.length() > 0) {     
        var currentNode = open_list.pop();
        
        if(currentNode.pos.x == goal.x && currentNode.pos.y == goal.y) {
            var path = [];
            var curNode = currentNode;
            
            while(true) {
                path.push(curNode);
                curNode = curNode.parent;
                if(curNode == undefined) break;
            }
            
            return(path);
        }
        
        closed_list.add(currentNode);
                
        for(var i=0; i<8; i++) {
            var neighbor = new PathNode(new Vector2(currentNode.pos.x + x_array[i], currentNode.pos.y + y_array[i]), 0, 0, 0);
            
            if(map.tiles[neighbor.pos.x][neighbor.pos.y].blocked == true) {
            canContinue = false;
        }
        
        for(var j=0; j<objects.length; j++) {
            if(objects[j].blocks == true && objects[j].position.x == neighbor.pos.x && objects[j].position.y == neighbor.pos.y) canContinue = false;
        }
        
        if(closed_list.hasNode(neighbor)) continue;
        if(!canContinue) continue;

            if(open_list.hasNode(neighbor)) { // if open_list contains neighbor, do this:
                neighbor = open_list.getNode(neighbor);
                neighbor.parent == currentNode;
                neighbor.g = currentNode.g + 10;
                neighbor.h = neighbor.pos.Manhattan(goal) * 10;
                neighbor.f = neighbor.g + neighbor.h;
                open_list.add(neighbor);
            } else { // otherwise it's not on the open list, do this:
                if(neighbor.g < currentNode.g) {
                    neighbor.parent = currentNode;
                    neighbor.g = currentNode.g + 10;
                    neighbor.f = neighbor.g + neighbor.h;
                }
                
                open_list.add(neighbor);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

I must be doing something wrong, because the code spirals into an infinite loop and crashes the browser whenever I run it. Could somebody point my error(s)?

Comment: I don't suppose you could post a sample input?

Comment: Sure, it would like look this: `FindPath(new Vector2(10, 10), new Vector2(15, 15));`, where Vector2 is a position class.

Comment: I mean could you set up a complete test case that breaks? I'm sure I could set one up but you must already have one. Saves me the trouble :) - Would be easier if we could see it attempting to work

Comment: Sure, go here: www.saege.bonfx.com/0.1.3. Open your console and press Shift-T to test pathfinding, which triggers the failure. I included my whole environment so you can view source if you want to see the rest of the scripts.

Comment: Sidenote: _awesome_ game so far

Comment: How can I keep up to date with it?

Comment: @aaaidan: I should have a site up for it shortly-- as you can see, it's still in the beginning stages. In the mean time, I've put up a page at the Roguelike Wiki (this game is a roguelike), which you can find here: www.roguebasin.roguelikedevelopment.org/index.php/Saege. Unfortunately that page is also a tad out of date as I've made a lot of progress since I last updated it a week or so ago. Still, I'll update it at some point in the near future. Appreciate the interest!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll update this answer with points as I find them.

- First of all I see no way to escape the outer loop in your
  environment. You have a console.log instead of a return statement, which you do have in your example posted here. `console.log(path);` instead of `return path;`
- You are not checking the closed list for nodes which have been closed. So once you have assessed the state of a node on the open list, it's pushed onto the closed list but you do nothing with that list. There is nothing preventing you from adding a node on the closed list to the open list again. You are only checking the open list for preventing the addition of the same node more than once. (Though your example code posted here shows that you are)

The combination of these things look like it will produce the same path infinitely many times.

Also just to point out, your example code is improperly indented so it looks like a lot of that code is not inside the 8 neighbours checking loop.

Comment: That's because I'm only looping while open_list.length() is larger than 0.

Comment: Yes but you want to exit as soon as you have found a path. That's why the A* algorithm uses a heuristic; to attain fast convergence.

Comment: Nonetheless, the algorithm should still work. I'll change that, though.

Comment: The test would work with the return statement in it. I actually get a path out from this. The forgetting to check the closed list allows you to follow circular paths, which is evidently what is happening here.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have forgotten to exclude unvisitable and closed nodes from your search.

Comment: I didn't forget, I just removed that code because it referenced some constructs I didn't want to have to include here primarily because they were pretty long. Sorry for not clarifing.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville Well, that's a pretty important part of the code, particularly the closed nodes, which are needed to avoid infinite recursion.